# Type mismatch when trying quit on ketpress

Tags: java

I've the below Java program.

```
package Arrays;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int size = 5; // Size of the input Array

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!input.equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the 5 number you want to be stored in an array");

            // get the input of array from the user
            int a[] = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                a[i] = input.nextInt();
            }

            /* Methods */
            System.out.println("\n");
            displayArray(a); // to display the numbers entered in Array
            System.out.println("\n");
            sumOfArray(a);// To print the sum of Array
            System.out.println("\n");
            productOfArray(a);// to print the product of Array
            System.out.println("\n");
            smallAndLargeOfArray(a);// to print the Max and Min number in Array
            System.out.println("\n");
            averageOfArray(a);// to print the average of Array
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        input.close();
    }

    private static void displayArray(int arr[]) {
        System.out.print("The numbers you have inserted are ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
            if (i < arr.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }

    }

    private static void sumOfArray(int[] arr) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        System.out.print("Sum of array is " + sum);

    }

    private static void productOfArray(int[] arr) {
        int prod = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            prod *= arr[i];
        }
        System.out.print("Product of array is " + prod);
    }

    private static void smallAndLargeOfArray(int arr[]) {
        int minimim = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (minimim > arr[i]) {
                minimim = arr[i];
            }
            if (maximum < arr[i]) {
                maximum = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Minimum and Maximum numbers in array are " + minimim
                + " and " + maximum);

    }

    private static void averageOfArray(int arr[]) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        double avg = sum / 5;
        System.out.print("Average of array is " + avg);

    }

}
```

here i was trying to continue the program till the user enters `q`, but here when i enter `q` it is throwing the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Arrays.Arrays.main(Arrays.java:16)
```

please let me know where am i going wrong and how can i fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are trying to compare an object of type String with an object of type Scanner. The result is always false, you enter the while loop and ask for `nextInt()` which causes a type mismatch because the next token is "q".

You should use input.findInLine() with a regular expression to look at the next token without consuming it and checking if it satisfies your breakout condition.

```
while(input.hasNextLine() && !input.findInLine("^q$")){
  //...
}
```

**Read:**

- [Getting User input with Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999899/getting-user-input-with-scanner)

EDIT:
Eddited to use `findInLine` which does not consume tokens.

Comment: but here i'm supposed enter only 5 numbers but it is giving me an option to enter 6th(The first is ignored).

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer. The method `findInLine` only looks at the input and does not consume it. The passed regular expression represents the letter _q_ as the first and last letter or a line. Check out the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)  of the Scanner class.

Answer (score 2):

You should do it as , because you are comparing your `Scanner` object

```
String inputName=""
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
inputName= in.nextLine();
        while (!inputName.equals("q")) {..}
```

as scanner object is not equal to "q" (which is a string), the while loop runs continuously. 
Then the scanner waits for an Integer, but it takes a character. So the scanner throws the exception (saying that the input cannot be converted into integer value)

**Read:**

- [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-could-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class)
- [Exception in thread main java.util.InputMismatchException error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249578/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-inputmismatchexception-error)

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown by the line:

```
a[i] = input.nextInt();
```

When you input a 'q', the next token cannot be cast to an int, so get an `InputMismatchException`. You should check if the next token is an int by using the `hasNextInt()` method.

Additionally, your condition `!input.equals("q")` does not make sense. Here, you check if the Scanner object is equal to the string "q". What you want to do is check whether the *next token* of the Scanner object is equal to the string "q":

```
boolean cont = true;
while (cont) {
    System.out.println("Enter the 5 numbers you want to be stored in an array");

    // get the input of array from the user
    int a[] = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            a[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        else {
            String token = input.next();
            if ("q".equals(token)) {
                cont = false;
                break;
            }
            i--; // move back to the last position
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Sysout outside the while loop and change your condition in while loop.

```
 System.out.println("Enter the 5 number you want to be stored in an array");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!input.next().equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the 5 number you want to be stored in an array");
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `nextInt()` which only expected int values. Change it to next() and cast the value to an int if it is not `q`